# Reading socket data multiple times in a row causes a connection drop

Tags: .net, postgresql

My name is Michel and am trying to write a Postgres connection driver with my lovely dotnet.

Postgres message protocol is simple - [int8 opcode] [int32 length] [payload].

I am trying to read the first five bytes from a stream to detect a message type and payload length. Then I am trying to read payload, which length I have to read in the previous step, and... connection getting closed by a Postgres. 
For example, we have a AuthMessage [uint8 opcode] [int32 length (always 8)] [int32 auth_type]

```cs
/// open a TCP connection, getting the stream, sending hello message
stream.Read(buffer, 0, 5);
/// parsing a buffer, creating a new one
stream.Read(buffer, 0, messageLenght - 4) // connection getting lost at this
```

The first packet is always the same length, so we can try to read all the 9 bytes in one step

```cs
/// open a TCP connection, getting the stream, sending hello message
stream.Read(buffer, 0, 9); // this works! no connection drop
```

how can I read the header packet bytes, parse them and read all the payload data in one action?

Comment: Are there enough bytes to read? Could msgLen-4 be negative?

Comment: No. MsgLen is always 4, so full message length is always 9